# How to draw a combination of circles with turtle graphics?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

How to draw a combination of circles by using turtle module in python, which are in touch with each other, but they need to have same center point and different radius.

Here is my same code of 4 circles having different radius and are in touch with each other and also there base point are align in a straight line, but I want the alignment of center point of these circles in a straight line not the base points.

If you can modify my code for this then it will be really helpful for me.

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
color = ["yellow","pink","red","orange"]
t.up()
t.forward(200)
j = 50
n = 0 
k = 120
for i in range(4):
    t.down()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.fillcolor(color[n])
    t.circle(j)
    t.end_fill()
    t.up()
    t.back(k)
    n=n+1
    j = j+20
    k = k+40
```

Comment: `same center point and different radius` - how can they touch?

Comment: Have you tried to investigate to figure out what is happening?  Try adding `t.pendown(); t.forward(600)` to the end - *outside* of the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the same pattern but taking only the centers of the circles in the same line and not the base, Here's an updated code:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.up()
color = ["yellow","pink","red","orange"]
t.forward(250)
j = 50
k = 120
for n in range(4):
    t.down()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.fillcolor(color[n])
    t.circle(j)
    t.end_fill()
    t.up()
    t.sety(-20*(n+1))
    t.back(k)
    j += 20
    k += 40
```

Comment: OP want the circles to *touch*.

Comment: @wwii I'm assuming by _touch_ he meant as in the borders touch (And if they are concentric all be it a thick border they do touch). Not quite sure if that's what was meant tho.

Comment: Try his solution and you may see the intent.

Comment: Looking at that I took it as center's in the same line not position. I updated my answer to reflect that (Got confused by the "same center point", I think it was written by mistake ). Anyway thanks for pointing that out.